# Como eu retiro caracteres alfabéticos de uma coluna de uma pd.Series? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Minha dúvida é bem simples. Dado uma pd.Series como descrita abaixo, como eu removo caracteres "ANOS" e "MESES" dela? Eu olhei a documentação do Pandas mas infelizmente não consegui descobrir um meio.

Eu fiz a seguinte variável para retornar a pd.Series:

In:

```py
idade_serie = dataframe['Idade'].value_counts()
```

Out:

```
80 ANOS     91
70 ANOS     85
73 ANOS     82
75 ANOS     81
76 ANOS     79
            ..
103 ANOS     1
17 ANOS      1
4 MESES      1
26 ANOS      1
19 AN0S      1
Name: Idade, Length: 109, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Tem que tomar cuidado com a forma que você quer fazer o count desses valores, retirando a string "ANOS" e "MESES" fará com que os números se unam no somatório do `value_counts()`, não sendo possível distinguir o que é o quê.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira é usar o método replace, porem para funcionar deve-se converter seu Dataframe para string.

Fiz um teste usando o seu caso, e ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Idade': ['80 ANOS', '80 ANOS', '80 ANOS', '80 ANOS', '80 ANOS',
                  '80 ANOS', '80 ANOS', '70 ANOS', '70 ANOS', '70 ANOS',
                  '73 ANOS ', '73 ANOS ', '73 ANOS ', '73 ANOS ']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
idade_serie = df['Idade'].value_counts()

print(df)
print('-'*40)
print(str(idade_serie).replace("ANOS", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando a função `.split()` por **espaço** e selecionando a primeira  posição do array, após isso usar a função `value_counts()`.

```
data = {'Idade': ['80 ANOS', '80 ANOS', '80 ANOS', '80 ANOS', '80 ANOS',
                  '80 ANOS', '80 ANOS', '70 ANOS', '70 ANOS', '70 ANOS',
                  '73 ANOS ', '73 ANOS ', '73 ANOS ', '73 ANOS ']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Idade'].str.strip().str.split(' ').str[0].value_counts()
#saida:
80    7
73    4
70    3
```

---

A função split quebra a coluna **Idade** pelo espaço, transformando os dados em arrays:

```
df['Idade'].str.strip().str.split(' ')
#saida
0     [80, ANOS]
1     [80, ANOS]
2     [80, ANOS]
3     [80, ANOS]
4     [80, ANOS]
5     [80, ANOS]
6     [80, ANOS]
7     [70, ANOS]
8     [70, ANOS]
9     [70, ANOS]
10    [73, ANOS]
11    [73, ANOS]
12    [73, ANOS]
13    [73, ANOS]
```

e o ultimo `.str[0]` serve para selecionar a primeira  posição de cada array:

```
df['Idade'].str.strip().str.split(' ').str[0]
#saida
0     80
1     80
2     80
3     80
4     80
5     80
6     80
7     70
8     70
9     70
10    73
11    73
12    73
13    73
```